# How can i change leaf position string by recursive permutation in C?

Tags: c, string, recursion, permutation

This is sample input output of my source code of generating permutation of alphabets string

```
Input:
1
3 8
Output:
Case 1:
ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CBA
CAB
```

I need to get `CAB` in line 5th and `CBA` in line 6th of this output, but I don't know how to do it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int N, M, count;
char array[27];

void swap (char array[], int i, int j) {
    char t;
    t = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = t;
}

void perm (char array[], int n, int i) {
    if(count == M)return;
    int j;
    if (i == n) {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++) printf ("%c", array[j]);
            count++;
        printf ("\n");
        return;
} else
    for (j=i; j<n; j++) {

        swap (array, i, j);
        perm (array, n, i+1);
        swap (array, i, j);
    }
}

int main () {
int v[27], i, testCase, T;
int tmp;
char tmpC;
scanf("%d", &T);
for(testCase = 1; testCase <= T; testCase++){
    scanf("%d %d", &N, &M);
    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        v[i] = i+1;
        tmp = i+65;
        tmpC = tmp;
        array[i] = tmpC;
    }
    printf("Case %d:\n", testCase);
    count = 0;
    perm (array, N, 0);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Black Moses for correcting the format. :)

Comment: @Weaher Vane ... Ok, I agree with you.But if i although use swap function, is there any way to get my expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the updated code for getting that expected output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int N, A[27], used[27], M;
string temp;
int counter;
void print()
{
int i;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    printf("%c", temp[i]);
printf("\n");
}

void solve(int i, int used[], string str)
{
if (counter == M) return;

if (i == N) {
    print();
    counter++;
    return;
}

for (int k = 0; k < N; k++){
    if (!used[k]){
        temp = str;
        temp += (char)(k + 'A');
        used[k] = 1;
        solve(i + 1, used, temp);
        used[k] = 0;
    }
}
}

int main()
{
int T;
scanf("%d", &T);
for (int testCase = 1; testCase <= T; testCase++){
    scanf("%d %d", &N, &M);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        used[i] = 0;
    counter = 0;
    printf("Case %d:\n", testCase);
    solve(0, used, "");
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your swap function won't do the job.  The algorithm you want appears to be one that prefers the elements according to their original order, so that it will *always* choose A over B over C, taking the first one available.  The swapping algorithm prefers the least change from the previous permutation.

To get the desired output, I think you need to change to a different algorithm, one that takes a single element (cycling through each in turn); for each choice, it recurs on the remainder of the list.

Comment: Thanks @Prune ...!

I've solved my problem by changing my algorithm and not using swap function.

Comment: Great!  Remember to up-vote helpful things and then choose an answer (or write one yourself) so that Stack Overflow can properly retire the question.